# Interaction of ocean waves and currents

Tags: waves, water, flow

I was on a small island recently near high tide.  As the tide started to go out, a tidal pond emptied into the ocean through a narrow channel with a strong outgoing current.  There was also wind on the ocean that was driving waves onto the shore of the island and part way up the channel.

I know that ocean waves are well described by a circular motion of the water and that the traveling waves are a superposition of standing waves that are 90 degrees out of phase but have no net current flow.  I initially guessed that to reconcile the outgoing current and the waves the current must be somehow diving under the waves.

I tested this by throwing a piece of wood into the current and watched it go out into the ocean.  Unlike my expectations, it stayed on top of the water the whole time and went up and down the waves as it went out into the ocean following the current.

What description of wave motion reconciles the current and the waves?

Answer (score 2):

The following picture (from http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/waves/imgwav/circonwave.gif) gives you a better sense of how to reconcile your observation with "circular motion":

[image]

As you can see - there *is* circular motion for particles at the surface: they don't have to go under water to do it though.

Incidentally this also shows that in the trough the water is flowing in the opposite direction from the wave direction: water is needed to "fill the peak" that will soon arrive.

Now the combination of a tidal current (steady outflow) and circular motion of the waves can be explained in a number of ways: you can have the entire body of water moving (translating), or you could have different layers of water moving by different amounts. Key to understand is that an apparent current of 1 m/s in 10 cm of water becomes an imperceptible current of 5 cm/s in 2 m of water...